# AppBarLayout to scroll only when scrolling upward and NOT when scrolling downward

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The scenario is I am using Coordinator Layout having CollapsingToolbarLayout inside of AppBarLayout. I have a RecyclerView just below the AppBarLayout.

Now say, I have many items in RecyclerView so that would be a lot of scrolling.

When scrolling up, the CollapsingToolbar/Appbar it is working perfect(i.e. Scrolling up it hides), but when I scroll down on the RecyclerView the CollapsingToolbar/Appbar scrolls down first(hence it becomes visible again fully) **NOT the items of RecyclerView** which leads to less space for showing the RecyclerView items.

How could I just achieve a type of scrolling so that it could behave like the AppBarLayout and RecyclerView were inside of a LinearLayout(for instance), hence Appbarlayout show appear only when the Parent is at the TOP scrolling position and should not appear when scrolling is mid-way in the RecyclerView.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
<AppBarLayout>
    <CollapsingToolbarLayout
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    >
    </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</AppBarLayout>

<RecyclerView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have somehting to do with your scroll flags. You specified `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"`

You should specify `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"` in order to scroll the CollapsingToolbarLayout only once your recyclerview is fully scrolled.